# Stuck on laptop logo on statup

Tags: windows, kali-linux, dual-boot

i had windows 10 on my laptop. Then i have added kali-linux as dual boot.On start up i would get GNU grub. But after setting my bios password i am stuck on the splash screen that is the logo of my laptop upon booting up. Any suggestion on how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

While I know this is a laptop, I don't know the brand so this is a bit of a leap.

I had this happen a while back myself but due to different circumstances.

I did a little digging and found this that should help you.

Removing the CMOS battery did the trick for me.

[Link to resetting BIOS password](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-reset-remove-bypass-a-bios-or-cmos-password/)